# Generic type for all class methods names with return type

Tags: typescript, class, generics

I am attempting to create a generic which will give me information about all class methods return types (+ fields, but they are not that important).

Let's say I have created such a class:

```js
class TestClass {
    testField: string;

    constructor() {
        this.testField = 'test';
    }

    testMethod1(param: number): number {
        return param;
    }

    testMethod2(param: string): string {
        return param;
    }

}
```

As the result, I would like to have such type:

```js
interface TestClassMethodsNamesReturnType {
  testMethod1: number;
  testMethod2: string;
}
```

#### What I have tried so far

- mapping types + types inference:

  **Example 1**

  ```js
  export type ClassMethodsNamesReturnType<T extends Function> = {
      [k in keyof T['prototype']]: ReturnType<T['prototype'][k]>;
  }

  const x: ClassMethodsNamesReturnType<TestClass> = {
      //...
  }
  ```

  Error:

  > Type 'TestClass' is missing the following properties from type 'Function': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more
- mapping types and treat class as object:

  **Example 2**

  ```js
  // I think here I can have problems to decide is the key of my class is a field or method 
  // what can be a problematic to decide what I should use (typeof T[K] or ReturnType<typeof T[K]>)
  export type ClassMethodsNamesReturnType<T extends Record<string, T[K]>, K extends keyof T> = {
      [K]: T[K];
  }
  ```

  Error:

  > A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type

  > 'K' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Do you have any hints or ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m35j3w) meet your needs? If so, I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  Note that your `TestClassMethodsNamesReturnType` example interface has repeated key names, apparently a typographical error (you should probably [edit] it).

Comment: @jcalz yep you are right (typo :/) If you would like to add your solution proposition into the answer, I will add +1. Sorry, but sno2 already added answer, so I cannot accept as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via mapped types although you would need to do a conditional filter using the `as` clause in the mapped type.  Then, check if the value extends `Function` and then return `never` if it does not so it will not be mapped over.  Here's the full code:

```
class TestClass {
    testField: string;

    constructor() {
        this.testField = 'test';
    }

    testMethod1(param: number): number {
        return param;
    }

    testMethod2(param: string): string {
        return param;
    }

}

type FnReturns<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Function ? K : never]: ReturnType<T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? T[K] : never> };

// Correctly passes:
const foo: FnReturns<InstanceType<typeof TestClass>> = {
    testMethod1: 23,
    testMethod2: "hey",
}

// correctly fails:
const fail: FnReturns<InstanceType<typeof TestClass>> = {}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8CwAoaB0SiSAYgJbwgAmAXNMgE7kB2A5gNx56HTAD2LJgFdgSfowAUASiw9ehJAAtyEAHTFkFKtWgBeaAHJNSQ13yEAvtwsETAWXjL+1AIySADmEZgAtvRZhXwAjeEZpAKDQxjlbBUYnYUYWaC8fX3Nea1x5OxJHZ2oAJk9vP3omVjYIhiRmdliFQgSkJJS0v0yrG2y8JABPD3hoUhYAJUTkiAAeWAA+fSxoAG0AaWhWaABreH7+ADM4aEg4NYBdaHgAD2IWahhSYRYxckFoAH5odYD4ADcws70CatZKwQbwWbnS43eB3GCSNSI7xsCD0MAsfrLM6yPQLdH9D6nVYXH7-RgLSzmPAAemp0BQEgSYhABK8UEQtDwAiESGg+34-Hoo2BbRmAEkeejgPAwUNpgMhgc4CQ0JAIHMFgYcHEHE4lC5XPQigBmAA0uSI+T1LiK9AAREpdnbzbherhaXxGfBmQT9mByCBUVzBMg+f6QELxpMhNMJcgpTLwfLwUqEMhVVANYtMJYgA)

Also note how I make use of the `InstanceType` of `typeof TestClass` to get the instance methods and properties of `TestClass`.

Comment: I didn't know about `InstanceType` nice one. Thx